# Powershell Cmdlet Alias Documentation

Tags: powershell, documentation

A nice feature of not adding documentation to dll cmdlets is that the cmdlet and parameter aliases, if they exist, are documented for free within get-help.

[image: No doc example]

However, the Alias section disappears when I provide a *.dll-help.xml file. Parameter aliases can be defined in xml via `<command:parameter aliases="">` but isn't reflected in the actual documenation. Nothing I've found gives an example on how to do this for the cmdlet itself.

Is there a way to retain the aliases section or parameter aliases, while also adding documentation?